# Sed: Finding and replacing a pattern that wraps around into next line

Tags: sed

I want to find and replace a pattern but it also wraps around to the next line as well, I need to find some way to handle this

Something that looks like:

```
....tr("Changes to output mappings will be deleted. "
"There is no undo available. Do you want to continue?"));
```

to turn into something like

```
...."Changes to output mappings will be deleted. "
"There is no undo available. Do you want to continue?");
```

(the ... is previous code)

So far, I have code such as (works for a single line but not wrapped text/code):

```
sed -i 's/tr(\([^)]*\))/\1/I' $file_t
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case where the `tr(` commands are always spread over two lines, try:

```
$ sed  '/tr(/N; s/tr(\([^)]*\))/\1/I' "$file_t"
...."Changes to output mappings will be deleted. "
"There is no undo available. Do you want to continue?");
```

The only change here is the addition of `/tr(/N`.  For any line that matches `tr(`, this reads in the next line and adds it to the pattern space (`N`).

To change the file in place, use `-i`:

```
sed  -i.bak '/tr(/N; s/tr(\([^)]*\))/\1/I' "$file_t"
```

#### More robust version

If it is possible that `tr(...)` commands may appear on one line, on two lines, or more than two lines, we need to change the logic a bit:

```
sed  '/tr(/{ :a; s/tr(\([^)]*\))/\1/I; t; N; ba}' filename
```

This looks for lines that contain `tr(`.  For any such lines, the commands in curly braces, `{...}`, are performed.  For those lines, the substitution is first attempted on that line only.  If the substitution happens, then the `t` command tells sed that we have completed this line.  If it didn't happen, meaning that there was no closing `)`, then the next line is read in (`N`) and sed branches back to label `a` (`ba`) and the substitution is tried again.  This repeats until enough lines are read in to find the `)`.

As an example, here is a file with `tr(...)` spread over one, two, and three lines:

```
$ cat filename
tr("abc");
....tr("Changes to output mappings will be deleted. "
"There is no undo available. Do you want to continue?"));
tr("one
two
three");
```

Here is the output:

```
$ sed  '/tr(/{ :a; s/tr(\([^)]*\))/\1/I; t; N; ba}' filename
"abc";
...."Changes to output mappings will be deleted. "
"There is no undo available. Do you want to continue?");
"one
two
three";
```

#### Distinguishing between `tr(...)` and `Ptr(...)`

To make sure that we substitute only for `tr` and not for `Ptr` or `Str`, we need to make sure that `tr` starts at a word boundary.  With GNU sed (Linux), a word boundary is denoted `\b`:

```
sed  '/\btr(/{ :a; s/\btr(\([^)]*\))/\1/I; t; N; ba}' filename
```

Using BSD (OSX) sed, [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5734237/3030305) might work:

```
sed  '/[[:<:]]tr(/{ :a; s/[[:<:]]tr(\([^)]*\))/\1/I; t; N; ba}' filename
```

Comment: `/tr(/{s///;:a;/)/! {n;ba};s///}`

Comment: wow, very good explanation and solution. Thank you

Comment: What about if there is something such as Ptr() or Str() that contains that tr string, is there any way to exclude those as well??

Comment: @user186523 Yes, that can be done.  I just added code for that to the end of the answer.

Comment: how about `perl -0777 -pe 's/\btr\(([^)]*)\)/$1/g' filename`